# Unlink function in php

Tags: php, function, unlink

**Is it possible to erase user-defined function?**

My CMS has one function, which I want to update with additions.

Trying to add some code to theme's code, that would make my code work only when this theme is switched on.

Comment: This is not possible, but your CMS probably has other solutions for extending it. Which CMS are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [rename_function()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) to rename the function you want to override to something else and then write the function under the original name.

Comment: This function comes from a debugger extension; and there are chances that it doesn't work with current php versions.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include or launch that code until the required theme is chosen.

My code for Default Theme from functions.php:

```
<?php
function sample()
{
    // the specific code here
}
```

Somewhere in the theme bootstrapping:

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
sample();

// OR inside a theme.

if ($theme_name == 'default')
{
    // Call the function
    sample();
}
```